# Use variable in custom number format VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a variable curr_code which stores the currency code taken from the spreadsheet/user as a string. It might take EUR/GBP/$ or whatever.

And I have a custom number format I use to format the numbers in the spreadsheet as desired:

```
.NumberFormat = "#,##0.00" & ";[COLOR 29]-#,##0.00" & ""
```

How can I allow this Number Format to add curr_code at the end of the number which is formatted.

ie, given curr_code = EUR, and the number was 670589.89474, it would be formatted as 670,589.89 EUR (including a space).

All help greatly appreciated,
Plastonick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can concatenate it into the format string - you must enclose it in quotes though:

```
.NumberFormat = "#,##0.00 """ & curr_code & """;[COLOR 29]-#,##0.00 """ & curr_code & """"
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you, I believe I was missing several quotation marks when I tried it like this!

Comment: @Gary'sStudent I left spaces after the 0.00 :)

Comment: Gary's Student, it seems to include a space for me, I copied and pasted directly from his code.